# Can't see new page source after JS onchange

Tags: javascript

I have a select menu which onchange creates another form. Before the onchange I view the page source HTML and after onchange it is the same. Should the source change? The new forms is being created correctly with Javascript.
Thanks Shane

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. This question is not right for superuser.com or for stackoverflow, so where can I ask it?

Comment: The answer to this is really simple, the page source doesn't show changes done with javascript, it shows ..... wait for it ......... the page source, being the actual code in the file. To see the changes, use the console instead.

Answer (score 0):

When choosing "view source", you're viewing the body response that the web server sent to your web browser.

In order to view the updated source (after you've manipulated the DOM in JS), you should use the Web Developer console. In Chrome, you can access this under "More Tools" -> "Developer Tools" -> "Elements".